# How should I write such a sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this.

```
id | a | b
1  | xxx | yyy |
2  | aaa | bbb |
```

Now, I have a value like yes or no. I want to full join them like following. For each record in table. I want to double it into two records, each one with yes or no.

How should I write such a sql? Thx. I am using MySQL.

```
id | a | b | whatever
1  | xxx | yyy | yes
2  | xxx | yyy | no
3  | aaa | bbb | yes
4  | aaa | bbb | no
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply cross join using a derived table:

```
select Row_Number() over(order by t.id, w.Whatever desc) Id,
    t.a, t.b,
    w.Whatever 
from (select 'Yes' Whatever union all select 'No') w
cross join t
```

Comment: Seems you have updated. Is this an optimized version?

Comment: It is a little complicated for me.

Comment: @Gorgine Yes I amended as I noticed you wanted `Id` to be numbered sequentially (not duplicated), which is the reason for adding the `rownumber`

Comment: ```select Row_Number() over(order by classes.id, w.Whatever desc) Id
from (select 'Yes' Whatever union all select 'No') w
cross join classes```

Comment: I run this sql, And it gave me syntax error.

Comment: Seems over function is not supported under version < 8.0.

Comment: Unfortunately analytic functions aren't supported by older versions of mysql, I made the hopeful assumption you were using the current version.